# Is free required for the temporary variable when you swap dynamic allocated variables in C?

Tags: c

Let assume that i want to swap a and b:

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *b = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *temp;

*a = 5;
*b = 10;
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

I have to free a and b later, but what about temp in that case?

doing the below is not creating any crash:

```
free(temp);
temp = NULL;
```

Does temp have to be freed?

Comment: No it's not required. `temp` and `a` point to the same memory block. So you only need to `free` one of them.

Comment: But your code does not swap the contents of the memory. Perhaps that's what you intend but just pointing it out.

Comment: I see but how would you swap the content of memory? printf show that a is now a = 10

Comment: With that made up example code it is difficult to say whether what you are doing is right or not. It depends on how `a` and `b` will ultimately be used. But to swap contents the code would be: `int temp; temp = *a; *a = *b; *b = temp;`

Comment: No. You don't need to; and can't, unless you assign its value to point to a `malloc`'ed memory address. If last assigned value was `temp = a`, then `free(temp)` is equivalent to `free(a)`. However, if you free `a` before `temp` (that is, `free(a)` following `free(temp)`), than the second `free` would raise error for trying to free an already freed memory space.

Comment: The code swaps the two pointers, @kaylum, so it’s fine as it stands.  It could be rewritten to swap the values pointed at but then `temp` wouldn’t be a pointer and there’d be no question of freeing it.

Comment: For each pointer returned by `malloc()`, there should be one `free()` of that pointer.  If you use `realloc()`, then you must not free the pointer passed to it but must `free()` (or re-`reallocate()`) the pointer returned.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation ssd , and Jonathan Leffler my thought was the same like yours about the swap

Comment: @ssd No, calling `free` twice on a pointer does not raise an error but invoke undefined behavior...let me explain: If we freed the memory, this memory chunk might have been allocated again by another `malloc()` request, and thus this double-free will actually free the wrong memory chunk

Comment: temp = a;  or *temp = *a; ?@JorhnMadsen

Comment: @RaHuL I'm not quite sure what you are asking me about, but i'm doing temp = a; as ' a ' is already a pointer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of `a`, `b`, or `temp` need to be freed. Named objects are managed by the C implementation. You never need to free them.

The memory allocated by `malloc` must be freed<sup>1</sup>. This is done by passing the address of the memory to `free`. It is entirely irrelevant whether this address is in `a`, `b`, or `temp`. The **value** returned by `malloc` is an address for the allocated memory. You may copy that value to many different places. When you free the memory, all that matters is that the value is passed to `free`. It does not matter whether it is in `a`, `b`, or `temp`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> The C standard does not require you to free memory, and, in any general-purpose multiuser operating system, you do not need to free memory when exiting your process, as `malloc` is only used to organize memory within your process. When the process exits, the operating system uses its own data structures to reclaim all the memory of your process. Freeing memory is needed inside your process to avoid wasting it when you stop using it. Freeing it releases it for other use. This is especially true if your program allocates a lot of memory over time—an accumulation of allocated memory that is not freed when it is no longer needed can cause unnecessary use of system resources and can cause severe performance degradation for your process and others. It can also cause your program to exhaust available memory and be unable to allocate more. On special-purpose embedded systems or in operating system kernel code, freeing allocated memory may be required.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation !